# Which of the following is an element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image: The Full Question entailed]

The full question is in the picture. Which of the following is an element? I feel that choice 1 is correct and choice 2 is wrong. It leaves me with the remaining two choices. I don't quite understand how the union of sets in here work. Can someone explain it to me the outcome of the union of the two sets? Answer can be more than 1 or none at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any set $A$, the set $A\cup \emptyset=A$. (Think of starting with $A$ and then adding nothing to it). Thus, your set in question is $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$. This set has two elements: $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: I see. What happens if the union happens with a null set in brackets?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you give an example?

Comment: the one in the question I gave is a null set which is not in a set. what happens if it is in a set? will the answer change? sorry for being a bit hard to understand.

Comment: If $A$ is a set and you are looking at $\{A\cup\emptyset\}$, then this is the set consisting of the element $A\cup\emptyset$, which is $A$. So, $\{A\cup\emptyset\}=\{A\}$.